# Error on NuGet Push to Gemfury from Azure DevOps Pipeline: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, gem-fury

I am trying to connect the nuget package output from my Azure DevOps CI build to Gemfury. However, I receive an error from the NuGet push step when pushing to Gemfury:

`Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).`

I am not sure how to connect to Gemfury from within Azure DevOps. I used the Azure DevOps Service Connection NuGet.

### Here is my build setup

**This is my NuGet service connection to Gemfury inside Azure DevOps:**
[image: Add NuGet service connection in Azure DevOps]

This uses the cURL connection type:
https://gemfury.com/help/upload-packages#cURL
 (I've tried it with both url types from Gemfury - https://nuget.fury.io/TOKEN/username/ and https://TOKEN@push.fury.io/username/)

It seems to be able to connect and authenticate to the service, when there isn't a nupkg to push. So I don't suspect there is an authentication issue.

**I then use this Gemfury Service Connection with a NuGet push task in my Azure DevOps Pipeline:**
[image: Gemfury Service Connection in Azure DevOps - NuGet]

**My nupkg exists as an artifact:**

[image: nupkg file exists in Artifacts]

**Here is the error I get on the NuGet push step of the Pipeline:**

[image: NuGet push error]

**I am able to manually copy the nupkg from the Azure DevOps build above and upload it to Gemfury:**

[image: Manual copy of nupkg results in Gemfury dashboard]

Any ideas?

[Here is a full list of available Service Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops) within Azure DevOps.

Comment: have you tried downloading nuget.exe and pushing to gemfury directly from your machine?

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, same result:

`Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).`

Comment: All I can suggest is contact Gem Fury support. NuGet has built-in support for api key and possibly HTTP basic authentication (but HTTP Basic auth is insecure, even when over HTTPS, so not recommended). However, if Gem Fury doesn't support NuGet's built in auth methods, they need to provide you with a NuGet Credential Provider, compatible with NuGet's Credential Provider API.  However, given your build is running on Azure DevOps, why don't you just use Azure Artifacts?

Comment: Thanks @zivkan. I initially contacted gemfury support, and they say they plan to support this, so I was hoping a SO post will help move things along. :) I'm currently using MyGet.org for package hosting (which has a more fitting consumption licensing model than Azure for my needs), and am looking at other options before upgrading to MyGet's Team pricing option.